# Order collection of items with multiple date fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a collection of items, where each item has these fields: `Title`, `DateCreated`, and `DateUpdated`

I want to order these items so that the most recent items are displayed first, where the most recent item is the one that was just created or update.

So if I created Item2 three seconds ago, it will show up on top. But if I then go update Item1, it will now show up on top, because Item1's `DateUpdated` is more recent than Item2's `DateCreated`

Is there a way to order a collection this way based on two dates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var newList = 
      list.OrderByDescending(s=>Math.Max(s.DateCreated.Ticks,s.DateUpdated.Ticks));
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create the item, just set both `DateCreated` and `DateUpdated` to the creation date. Then you can just order by the `DateUpdated`.

Comment: That would be ideal, but unfortunately I'm working with an older application that already has thousands of records, and I have no control over changing the code to set both `DateCreated` and `DateUpdated` on creation. But good answer :)

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong then you are using custom data for your collection. so you will have to use IComparable interface in order to achieve it. Here is the reference "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx "

Comment: no need to implement `IComparable`!The `DateTime` class internally implements IComparable interface!He is going to sort by `DateTime`!